# How to get page context in MOODLE

Tags: moodle

How do we get the context of the current page opened in moodle
i.e., the context could be either system/course/coursecat etc.,

I would appreciate your help

Answer (score 4):

Really simple :)

```
$context = $PAGE->context;
```

And to check the type of context, use the context constants

```
switch ($context->contextlevel) {
    case CONTEXT_SYSTEM:
        break;
    case CONTEXT_USER:
        break;
    case CONTEXT_COURSECAT:
        break;
    case CONTEXT_COURSE:
        break;
    case CONTEXT_MODULE:
        break;
    case CONTEXT_BLOCK:
        break;
}
```

Comment: That does assume that something on the page has already set up the context for you - either by calling 'require_login($course, [true], [$cm]);' or by calling '$PAGE->set_context($context);'

Comment: Yes.. davosmith was right, we could the current page by  $context = $PAGE->context;
$coursecontext = $context->get_course_context(); $courseid = $coursecontext->instanceid;

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following set before you call $PAGE:

```
GLOBAL = $PAGE;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).